# GDI+ How to fix FPS drop using PNG image?

Tags: png, gdi+

Sorry for my bad English.

Currently I am using this way.

```
Gdiplus::Image img(L"xxx.png");
Gdiplus::Graphics g(hdc);
g.DrawImage(&img,0,0);
```

When I use PNG if I draw over 400*200 pixel my FPS drop the 39~45.

but instead use BMP image FPS keep maintain 60.

How I can fix this problem?.

convert pixelformat

I use this way(doesn't work)

```
 img = Image::FromFile(filename);
 bmp = new Bitmap(img->GetWidth(), img->GetHeight(), PixelFormat32bppPARGB);
 Graphics gra(hdc);
 gra.FromImage(bmp);
 gra.DrawImage(img, destX, destY, img->GetWidth(), img->GetHeight());
```

Comment: Your initialization of the Graphics object is wrong. Try something like `Graphics * gra = Graphics::FromImage(bmp);` Sorry but I'm not too familar with C++

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is due to the PixelFormat.

GDI(+) uses PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb internally. All other formats are converted when drawing. The conversion is likely causing your performance issue.

So if you want to draw a picture frequently, convert it yourself on load instead having GDI doing it on each draw.

**EDIT:**

The PixelFormat can be "converted" like this:

```
// Load png from disc
Image png = Image.FromFile("x.png");
// Create a Bitmap of same size as png with the right PixelFormat
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(png.Width, png.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
// Create a graphics object which draws to the bitmap
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
// Draw the png to the bmp
g.DrawImageUnscaled(png, 0, 0);
```

Be aware that Image, Bitmap and Graphics objects implement IDisposable and should be properly disposed when no longer required.

Cheers

Thomas

Comment: Thanks!  I try to several things convert PixelFormat. but it doesn't work at all. Could you tell me an example How to?

Comment: Sorry. 
It doesn't work too.
And I am using WIN32 API.  Your example not suitable WIN32 API.